# allow anonymous post to organic groups

Tags: 6, users, organic-groups

Does organic groups allow anonymous posts of content to groups?

I want to enable a simple workflow on my site running organic groups - anonymous users should be able to post blog entries to groups. I've got permissions set up so that anonymous can post blog entries, and blog entries are a group type, but I can't get it to let them associate a new blog post with a group.  Logged in as admin I can do this just fine.

**Debugging Notes**

I dug into og to see if it was a permissions issue.  It looks like `og_form_add_og_audience` isn't adding the `og_groups` array to the form.  Looking at the logic in that function, I don't see where it would add all the groups for an anonymous user.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to make this work, so I ended up setting up a "fake anonymous" user in its own module - a bit of a superhack that I'm not happy with.  That said, it works.  This "fake anonymous" user id is set via an admin settings page, and gets added to every group created.  When new posts are created I added a form hook to change the author to this "fake anonymous" user id if the submitter is anonymous.  Maybe this is easier in D7?